# Distinct array of objects by smallest object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, distinct

I have an array of objects:

```
    [{Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "5000" },
    {Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "2000" },
    {Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "500" },
    {Name: "Company 2", AddressName: "Address 2", Radius: "500" },
    {Name: "Company 3", AddressName: "Address 3", Radius: "3000" },
    ...]
```

Some companies can occur in different radii, so in the array they occur several times.

What i want: if a company with the same name and address occurs several times in the array, only one company with the smallest radius should remain:

```
    [{Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "500" },
    {Name: "Company 2", AddressName: "Address 2", Radius: "500" },
    {Name: "Company 3", AddressName: "Address 3", Radius: "3000" },
    ...]
```

Comment: great. do you have some code, you tried?

Comment: have you tried reduce ?

Comment: @NinaScholz, i'm pretty newbie in JS, so i've tried only loop with comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
 {Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "5000" },
 {Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "2000" },
 {Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "500" },
 {Name: "Company 2", AddressName: "Address 2", Radius: "500" },
 {Name: "Company 3", AddressName: "Address 3", Radius: "3000" },
];
const res = arr.sort((a, b) => +a.Radius - +b.Radius)
 .filter((a, i) => arr.findIndex((b) => a.Name === b.Name && a.AddressName === b.AddressName) === i);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution without sorting in advance.

---

Basically you need a grouping by `Name` and an additional filtering by minimizing `Radius` for every group.

This approach tries to find the index of the same group and if not found `index === -1`, it pushes the actual object to the result set.

Otherwise if the numerical value of `Radius` of the stored object is greater than the actual object, the object in the result set is replaced with the actual object.

```js
var data = [{ Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "5000" }, { Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "2000" }, { Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "500" }, { Name: "Company 2", AddressName: "Address 2", Radius: "500" }, { Name: "Company 3", AddressName: "Address 3", Radius: "3000" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var index = r.findIndex(q => q.Name === o.Name);
        if (index === -1) r.push(o);
        else if (+r[index].Radius > +o.Radius) r[index] = o;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

If you like to have it more functional and to be loosly based on SQL, like the following query,

```
SELECT Name, AddressName, MIN(Radius) 
FROM data 
GROUP BY Name;
```

you could group first and take the min object out of the result sets.

```
result = pipe(
    groupBy('Name'),
    select(max('Radius'))
)(data);
```

```js
const
    pipe = (...functions) => input => functions.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), input),
    groupBy = key => array => array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = r.find(([p]) => o[key] === p[key])
        if (temp) temp.push(o);
        else r.push([o]);
        return r;
    }, []),
    min = key => array => array.reduce((a, b) => +a[key] < +b[key] ? a : b),
    select = fn => array => array.map(fn);


var data = [{ Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "5000" }, { Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "2000" }, { Name: "Company 1", AddressName: "Address 1", Radius: "500" }, { Name: "Company 2", AddressName: "Address 2", Radius: "500" }, { Name: "Company 3", AddressName: "Address 3", Radius: "3000" }],
    result = pipe(
        groupBy('Name'),
        select(min('Radius'))
    )(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from @ponury-kostek,

```
// this will return object
    var c = test.sort((a,b) => +b.Radius - +a.Radius).reduce((a,d)=>{
      a[`${d.Name}:${d.AddressName}`] =  d;
      return a;
    },{});

// this will convert to array of objects
    var res = Object.keys(c).reduce((a,d)=>{
      a.push(c[`${d}`]);
      return a;
    },[]);
```